# Right User Permissions to use ListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions method

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm currently using a SharePoint account as a Service account to get files and share them in an application I'm working on using **CSOM**. I filter the files according to the logged-in user to check if the user has no access to the file, then I hide it, to prevent him from trying to access it and get "Permission Denied" error.

So, I used `ListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions` for this issue, but I need to grant the user only the permissions he needs to access and make that check.

I checked the official documentation of `ListItem.GetUserEffectivePermissions` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536458(v=office.15)) but unfortunately, I found no direct clue which permission does the job.

So to recap what this service account needs to do is :

1- Execute Search across all sharepoint files [SearchExecutor].

2- Get Login Name by Email using `Utility.ResolvePrincipal` (to be used in `GetUserEffectivePermissions` function).

3- Use `GetUserEffectivePermissions` to check if the logged-in User has permission to view the file.

I'd really appreciate your help as I'm kind of new to SharePoint and I searched a lot but found no clue about what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you change your architectural approach.  Instead of trying to manage what permissions a user has in SharePoint, let SharePoint take care of it like it already does.  Instead, have your app use an OBO (On Behalf Of) token which will honor the logged on user's permissions in SharePoint and only return items that the user has access to.  For a detailed overview of the OBO flow in MSAL, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) article.